# Matching with probabilities and counts

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a set mobile device data. An impression (data point) is received when the user downloads a specific app. When the impression is received, it includes the device's id, geographic location, and the timestamp. By analyzing usage patterns for each user and interaction between time of day, day of the week, number of impressions at a location, etc... I  want to determine the location that is most likely to be home address of the mobile device user. For example,

Id 1 could have the following usage pattern

On Sunday October 11 at 8:15 AM at location (A1) with latitude of 40.748817 and  longitude of -73.985428 and impression was received.

On Sunday October 11 at 8:15 AM at location (A1) with latitude of 40.748817 and  longitude of -73.985428 and impression was received.

On Sunday September 27 at 8:15 AM at location (A1) with latitude of 40.748817 and  longitude of -73.985428 and impression was received.

On Sunday September 20 at 8:15 AM at location (A1) with lattitude of 40.748817 and  longitude of -73.985428 and impression was received.

Thus, we have a total of 4 impressions (visits) that occur at the unique (day of the week,hour, minute) tuple of (Sunday,8,15)., i.e., 4 total (visits) to location A1 with this unique tuple.

We also have

On Sunday October 4 at 8:15 AM at location (A3) with latitude of 40.748809 and  longitude of -73.985371 and impression was received.

On Sunday October 18 at 8:15 AM at location (A3) with latitude of 40.748809 and  longitude of -73.985371 and impression was received.

On Sunday September 20 at 8:15 AM at location (A3) with latitude of 40.748809 and  longitude of -73.985371 and impression was received.

Thus, we have a total of 3 impressions (visits) that occur at the unique (day of the week,hour, minute) tuple of (Sunday,8,15)., i.e., 3 total (visits) to location A3 with this unique tuple.

Thus, we have 7 total visits that occur at the unique tuple (Sunday,8,15) with 4 occurring at location A1 and 3 occurring at location A3, so we have the total visits percentage for location A1 on the tuple (Sunday,8,15) equal to 57% and the total visits percentage for location A2 on the tuple (Sunday,8,15) equal to 43%.

Id 1

```
           Location  day    hour  min Total Visits_Percentage   
             A1      Sunday   8    15    4        .57                            
             A1      Sunday   8    30    4        .57
             A2      Monday  15     0    2        .66
             A2      Tuesday 15     0    2        .33
             A2      Tuesday 11    15    1        1.0
             A3      Saturday 1    30    2        1.0
             A3      Saturday 1    45    1        1.0
             A3      Saturday 2     0    1        1.0
             A3      Sunday   8    15    3         .43
             A3      Sunday   8    30    3         .43
```

I have training data that has specific probabilities for home on any given (day of the week, hour, min) tuple.

For example, for the (Sunday,8,15) tuple, there is a probability of 41.2% that a visit (impression) to a location on this specific (day of the week, hour tuple) means that the location is the actual home of the device user. Similarly for the  (Sunday,8,30) tuple the probability is 41.9%, for (Monday,15,0) the probability  is 32.3%,…

I want to set up a model that either returns the probability that each of the id’s location is the home, i.e.,

```
   A1= .52
   A2= .19
   A3= .49
```

Or explicitly classifies each location as “home” or “not home”. I welcome any ideas on an existing model that may fit this problem or strategies to build a custom algorithm.

Comment: Would you please describe what Total is? and What Visists_Percentage means? I think you need to clarify what exactly each column means.

Comment: @Afshin I tried to be as explicit as possible. The data is proprietary and the question is rather complex, but essentially I'm trying to determine the influence of when an impression is received (DOW, hour, minute)  on the identification of the home of a mobile device user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can formulate your problem as a classification model where samples/users are:

```
loc1-mon loc1-tue loc1-wed ... loc2-mon ... loc2-sun ... loci-dayi
```

and the values of each of these features is the percent of visits they have in each location.
Then for some users you need to know their home location. You use these gold labels as training samples and learn a classifier that given the percent of visits in each location-day finds if the user lives in loc1, loc2, ... or locn. locations are labels.

Does this seem to be an answer? I usually use scikit-learn in Python to train such models because it is so easy to use.